# Placement of MOSFETs in switchable voltage divider for voltage measurements

Tags: voltage, analog, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

In my battery powered application I am using a switchable voltage divider to not drain the battery. I have seen switchable voltage deviders in two versions:

- MOSFET at the bottom
- MOSFET in the middle

The left version seems to be better from my perspective because one does not need to take the voltage drop across R3 into account for the level of the enable signal.

What can be the reason to put the MOSFET in the middle and are there situations when one version has to be prefered to the other?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSqkqj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The expected range of Ubat is an important part of the problem specification. If R2 and R1 divide 300V down to 3V3 for example, and you turn M1 off ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What can be the reason to put the MOSFET in the middle and are there
> situations when one version has to be prefered to the other?*

Putting the MOSFET "in the middle" is totally ineffective as a means of measuring the voltage U_BAT because the MOSFET acts like a source follower and the source voltage becomes whatever voltage is on the gate minus a 1 or 2 volts. Totally NOT reflective of U_BAT.

Putting a MOSFET "at the bottom" does actually guarantee your potential divider does its job with tiny on-resistance errors that are usually so minor they can be discarded. However, when the MOSFET is inactive, you have to be careful that R4 is large enough to prevent significant currents into your MCU pin from U_BAT.

The generally preferred method is a MOSFET "at the top" but that comes with extra circuit complexity: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337058/low-current-divider-for-battery-voltage-monitoring). Now, the "undesirable" and somewhat unpredictable current flow into the MCU measurement pin is eradicated.

Comment: May we also have your thoughts on putting a mosfet at the top instead?  To protect from the higher voltage that is.

Comment: @KH of course, I was on it!

Comment: Thank you!  I'd upvote again if I could lol

Comment: @Andy aka Doesn‘t the MOSFET in the middle also have some advantages? If R4 is much bigger than R3 (say 29k and 1k) and I want to break down a maximum voltage of 45V then this works fine because the current through R3 does not raise the source of M2 to much. (Circuit in the question) Also with this version only one Transistor is necessary and there is on pull up effect to the MCU Pin when there is on Enable signal present. On the downside my resolution is decreased.

Comment: I’m sure you could make a case for it working in a limited range of scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Having the MOSFET at the bottom simplifies driving it. However, think about the voltage at the MCU-pin, when the MOSFET is turned off. You are basically applying the battery voltage to the MCU input pin via R2. This can damage the MCU. For low voltage batteries, this might be fine. Look at the MCU datasheet to determine if applying your battery voltage directly to the input pin can be dangerous.

Comment: Mayhaps the mosfet would be best placed at the top?  Like an nMOS switching a pMOS?